# Populate second model in same view in MVC : Prevent postback

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, syncfusion

I have a page in MVC, where i need to display the details of the records.
The records needed to be fetched from 2 tables for which i have Model separately.
Now, for this page needing both the models, I have created another model which have those 2 model referred.

[Please note, following nomenclature's are only for example purposes.]

```
public class CombinedModel
{
    public Model1 objModel1 { get; set; }
    public Model2 objModel2 { get; set; }
}
```

In the view [Details.cshtml], I have following code:

```
@model Application.Web.Models.CombinedModel

<div>
    @Html.Label("Label text: ", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.objModel1.Property1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
</div>
```

And a popup code

```
<div id="Modal">
    <div>
        @Html.Label("Popup label text:", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
        @Html.DisplayFor(vmodel => vmodel.objModel2.Property2, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    </div>
 </div>
```

The page loads with the data in from the first model successfully from controller action.
 I needed Data in the popup code, only when user clicks on particular record, from where View will send ID and will display record for that particular ID from the second model.

In Controller:

```
public class ControllerNameController : Controller
 {
    [HttpGet]
    [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "None")]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult Details(int? Id, string strType, string strVersionID)
    {
        var Details1 = db.Table1.FirstOrDefault(rd => rd.SomeID == Id);
        CombinedModel modelCombined = new CombinedModel();
        Model1 objectM1 = new Model1();
        objectM1.Property1 = Details1.Column1;


        var VersionDetails = db.Table2.FirstOrDefault(rvd => rvd.somePrimaryKeyID == Convert.ToInt32(strVersionID));
        if (VersionDetails != null)
        {
            Model2 objectM2 = new Model2();
            objectM2.vCreatedOn = VersionDetails.Property2;
            modelCombined.objModel2 = objectM2;
            ViewBag.VersionID = VersionDetails.VersionID;
        }

        modelCombined.objModel1 = objectM1;
        return View(rmodel);
    } 

 }
```

The page landing URL is:

```
function JavascriptFunctionInParentView(IDToPass, strTypeToPass)
 {
    top.location.href = "@Url.Action("Details", "ControllerName")" 
                        + "?Id=" + IDToPass
                        + "&strType='" + strTypeToPass + "'"
                        + "&strVersionID='0'";
 }
```

SO, when first time page loads, we have strVersionID as Zero. So, it will not enter in VersionDetails block and fill only Model1 data.

Now, when we are Details page, there is a grid, from which, I need to populate the version details in the popup, for which I have working code as following:

```
 function recordDoubleClickRuleVersion(args) {
            top.location.href = "@Url.Action("Details", "ControllerName")" 
                                + "?Id=" + @Url.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString["Id"]
                                + "&strType=" + '@Url.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString["strType"]'
                                + "&strVersionID=" + args.data.VersionID;
 }
```

// ....

```
$(function () {
        if ('@(ViewBag.VersionID)' == "") {
            $("#Modal").ejDialog("close");
        }
        if ('@(ViewBag.VersionID)' != "") {
            $("#Modal").ejDialog(
                     { enableModal: true, enableResize: false, close: "onDialogClose", width: "60%" });
            $("#Modal").ejDialog("open");
        }
    })
```

My problem is, when i call this Version details popup, page postbacks and then data comes.. I know i have given @Url.Action to it so it is behaving like this way.
 I needed it to be by complete Client-side code and I tried following code as well. It open's popup but doesn't fill value in it.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        data: ({
                "Id": @Url.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString["Id"],
                "strType": '@Url.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString["strType"]',
                "strVersionID": args.data.VersionID }),
        url: '@Url.Action("RuleDetails", "Rules")',
    })
    .done(function (RuleVersionDetails) {
        // 1. Set popup 
        $("#Modal").ejDialog(
         { enableModal: true, enableResize: false, close: "onDialogClose", width: "60%" });
        // 2. Open popup 
        $("#Modal").ejDialog("open");
    });
```

Can you please tell me the solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can change you Details() Action to return a Json object, and then fill the dialog with it.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    data: ({
            "Id": @Url.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString["Id"],
            "strType": '@Url.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString["strType"]',
            "strVersionID": args.data.VersionID }),
    url: '@Url.Action("RuleDetails", "Rules")',
})
.done(function (jsonData) {
    // **TODO: file dialog with properties of jsonData**
    // 1. Set popup 
    $("#Modal").ejDialog(
     { enableModal: true, enableResize: false, close: "onDialogClose", width: "60%" });
    // 2. Open popup 
    $("#Modal").ejDialog("open");
});
```

Comment: Yes. I did that when i was calling using $.ajax request. But it still does not fills the data.

Comment: It should work because in my project I have done that many many times :).

Answer (score 0):

The best approach for your case is using bootstrap modal.Go [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) and check its documentation and how to config. If you aren't familiar with bootstrap or modal, it really worth to learn.

But remember when you want sent data to modal section, make it dynamic based on your item id in grid.

Comment: Bro, I know bootstrap.. My concern is not of which Modal popup I use, I need the proper way to bind that back to my view without postbacking.

Comment: Using modal means you need jQuery and that means you don't postback